# MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04. I have installed `mysql-workbench` and I am getting this error when I am launching it:

```
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgdkmm-2.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: remove directory  `/usr/lib/mysql-workbench` and also `/usr/local/bin/mysql-workbench*`, then update and then again install

Comment: How did you install `mysql-workbench`?

Answer (score 18):

Try to reinstall the `mysql-workbench`.

To be sure you don't lose your connection data, copy following file: `~/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml`

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Or do the following to clean up system (after upgrade to higher Ubuntu version):

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get clean
```

[Install workbench from official website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (select the correct Ubuntu version).

Comment: I have done that, but each time I am getting the same error when I launch mysql-workbench

Comment: Seems like their went something wrong with the upgrade to 16.04.  Execute the second code part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. For 18.04 and 19 Ubuntu download the deb file from [MySQL Downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=490465)
2. Before installing just downloaded mysql-workbench deb file, first download the libzip4 from [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=490465)
   and install the libzip4 using software installation
3. Run this command in your terminal

   ```
   sudo apt --fix-broken install
   ```
4. Then run this command

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.18-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
   ```

Note: In case if you are unable to install you may require to download and install `mysql-apt-config` before Step 2